# Change "90 days" to "6 months" in public beta notice on Area 51, and change progress bar speed if possible

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, beta-phase, beta-sites

On proposals for sites in public beta, in the top right, Area 51 displays the following text regarding public beta sites

> Sites remain in beta for at least 90 days to build up a critical mass of users, questions, and participation.

However, according to the [most current site lifecycle process](https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com/a/108/1908), the minimum time a site must spend in public beta is six months.

Recently, the text in the same spot for *private* beta site proposals was updated to the most current process:

> Everyone can participate and invite fellow experts. Committers were notified of the Private Beta launch.
>
> The site will have up to 5 weeks to qualify for Public Beta.

(For context, the text originally said only committers could participate, and said the timeline was only one week, later three weeks.)

Can the text for *public* beta sites please be updated as well? In particular, the "90 days" in the text should be changed to "6 months", and the first part of the sentence should be changed to "Sites remain in public beta" (the 90 days formerly included time in private beta).

While we're at it, it would also be nice if the progress bar was updated as well. Currently, it grows from the end of "commitment" to the very end in just 90 days, as that was the minimum time for the beta phase. This should be updated to take 215 days (five weeks private beta plus six months public beta).

Answer (score 8):

We've updated the sidebar text and the progress bar calculation. It still won't be perfect since timelines for sites do tend to be a little fluid, but it should at least be closer to the right ballpark.

Thanks for the request!

Comment: The "on pace for [x] users at 90 days" numbers seem to have been updated to the new progress calculation, but still mention 90 days. Can that please be fixed as well?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Good call, I updated that spot as well.